# Make the action of a notification

Tags: android

I'm new to android so I need some help. I have a sound that is playing in background and I want to make a notification when the user wants to play another sound...any ideas? Thank you very much! Please help!:*

Comment: "I want to make a notification when the user wants to play another sound" - pls explain what kind of notification etc ?? what do you want exactly and post your code

Comment: Let say you want to listen a song from a play list...you minimize the media player and you navigate on your phone and when you want to play another sound file from your phone a notification appears that brings on the front your application

Comment: did I make it clear for you?

Comment: Would you please clarify what you mean by *notification*? Do you mean the [android standard notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)?

Comment: These types of questions are not well suited for this site. Why not show us what you've tried. What's going wrong (i.e., why is it different than what you expected)? FYI - I'm new to Android and I bought a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`Notification.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) for creating the notification. Set a [`PendingIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) on it and handle it. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html) is another tutorial on Notifications.